# Puppeteer: How to select options in a form

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to select an option in a form. The select element in form does not have id, but it has a name attribute. However I am not able to select the option, instead its getting exception. Code is as below.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select');
  await sleep(5000);
  await page.select('select[name=cars]', 'Saab');
  await sleep(15000);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

It is throwing an exception as below.

> (node:15904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to
>   find element matching selector "select[name=cars]"
>       at ElementHandle.$eval (/home/austin/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js:435:13)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)   -- ASYNC --
>       at ElementHandle. (/home/austin/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at DOMWorld.$eval (/home/austin/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:156:21)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) (node:15904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection.

Please let me know why Puppeteer page.select not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is correct, unfortunatelty the target site you chose for practice is a little bit more complicated than usual sites, because it shows content you're after in an iframe and this method:

```
await page.select('select[name=cars]', 'Saab');
```

only looks for elements in the main frame.

So we need to find an iframe with demo HTML first (and probably wait for it to load first, as it is generated by scripts and is not available after page load right away). We could wait for an arbitrary period of time (like `page.waitFor(5000)`) but it is too unstable — who knows how much time you'll need in a real case of scraping?

I'll provide further description as comments in the corrected script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// this utility's from [1]
function waitForFrame(page) {
  let fulfill;
  const promise = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);
  checkFrame();
  return promise;

  function checkFrame() {
    // either find an existing iframe
    // note that we know the name of that iframe
    const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframeResult');
    if (frame)
      fulfill(frame);
    else
      // or wait for the event when it will have been created
      page.once('frameattached', checkFrame);
  }
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select');

  // Wait for an iframe with demo HTML
  const frame = await waitForFrame(page);

  // Now wait for the element we need to appear, we won't rely on a fixed timeout
  // Note that we're waiting on the previously discovered "frame", not the usual "page"
  await frame.waitForSelector('select[name=cars]');

  // Set the desired value, note that it is lowercase, as in option's value
  await frame.select('select[name=cars]', 'saab');

  // Confirm we did it right
  await page.screenshot({path : "screen.jpg"});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

---

Result screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nivwm.jpg

---

[1] https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1361#issuecomment-343748051

Comment: Sure, see the screenshot. It works on 1.18.1, what's your version and what's the exception now? Does the target page open for you?

Comment: Its working now. Once I got exception, now it is working fine. Not sure why I got first time exception.